# Transform plain data into json file

Tags: debian, text-processing, json

everyone.
I am quite new with linux and I am learning a lot with all of you reading this site. I am into a bit of trouble with my accounting program and that's why I am recurring to you. I want to move my data from plain text to json, what I believe will give me better results and more flexibility.

I have a folder containing info in separated files.
The files are like this:

```
20170404
pago
80051442-4
002-001-0080057
310000


310000
si
2017-06-05
```

I want to copy this info in new files where each line is a new json field. Something like this:

```
{
"field1":"20170404",
"field2":"pago",
"field3":"80051442-4",
"field4":"002-001-0080057",
"field5":"310000"
"field6":"",
"field7":"";
"field8":"310000"
"field9":"si"
"field10":"2017-06-05"
}
```

I am looking for a script to read the whole directory and build these new files: oldfile.json.

And after that I want to tab results of several of these files in different columns:

```
file1    field1    field2    field3   field4    field5    field6    field7
file2    field1    field2    field3   field4    field5    field6    field7
file3    field1    field2    field3   field4    field5    field6    field7
file4    field1    field2    field3   field4    field5    field6    field7
file5    field1    field2    field3   field4    field5    field6    field7
```

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: Where is 'Contado' coming from? Where does 'pago' go?

Comment: what does mean *to tab results of several of these files* in context of converting to json ?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. 'Contado' is 'pago' now in output too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to the second part - converting json files to table.

**Usage:** `./json_to_table.sh *.json`

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in "$@"; do
    file_content=$(sed -n 's/".*":"\(.*\)",\?/\1/p' "$i" | tr '\n' ' ')
    printf "%s %s\n" "$i" "$file_content"
done | column -t
```

If you don't need pretty table format, then you may remove  `| column -t` part (in the bottom, after `done`). Then row's fields will be separated by one space, therefore, each will have own width. It is good for parsing by programs, like `awk`, `sed`, but inconvenient for humans reading.

**Note:** after each record in the json file, except last, should be comma. What I mean:

```
"field8":"310000", <- here
"field9":"si", <-here
"field10":"2017-06-05" <- not here. Last record without comma.
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was asking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I changed the code a little bit, use this variant. In the previous variant could be a problem with comma inside the records (`tr` removes all commas in the text).

Answer (score 6):

I would solve this using [***jq***](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) tool (a proper JSON parsing/manipulating tool):

```
for f in *; do
    jq -R -s 'rtrimstr("\n") | split("\n") | to_entries | reduce .[] as $o ({}; .["field" + ($o.key+1|tostring)] |= $o.value )' "$f" > "$f".json; 
done
```

---

- `-R`(`--raw-input`) combined with `-s`(`--slurp`) - pass the entire input to the filter as a single long string

Answer (score 1):

```
for file in *; do
    awk 'BEGIN { print "{" }  END { print "\n}" } { printf( "%s",newrec); printf( "\"field%d\": \"%s\"", NR, $0); newrec=",\n" }' "$file" > "${file}.json"
done
```

`NR` is the Number of Records (or lines) in the file that have been processed so far.  It's `1` when working on line one, `2` on line two, and so forth.

`$0` is the entire unmodified input record (or line).

If the names of the fields are the same, you can define an array (e. g. `labels[]`) in the `BEGIN` stanza, and then refer to them by index (e. g. `labels[NR]`).

Comment: It works great, only I don't understand a few thinks about your code. If you could explain what the `, NR, $0` stand for ... And would it be possible to obtain the name of the fields from an array? That would be of great help to modify other files i want to transform into json.

Answer (score 0):

So final script for the first part is:

```
for file in facturas/*; do
    awk 'BEGIN {
        split("fechae tpago ruc nfactura total iva10 iva5 iva0 archivado fechap",campos)
        print "{" 
    }
    END {
        print "\n}" 
    }
    {
        printf( "%s",newrec)
        printf( "\"%s\":\"%s\"", campos[NR], $0)
        newrec=",\n"
    }' "$file" > "${file}.json"
done
```

And final result for second part:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in "$@"; do
    printf "%s " "$i"
    sed -n 's/".*":"\(.*\)"/\1/p' "$i" | tr ',\n' ' ' 
    echo
done | column -t
```

Thank you everyone for your interest.